# How do I see that $a^2 \equiv 1 \mod{( p \cdot q)}$ has four incongruent solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, cryptography

How do I see that $a^2 \equiv 1 \mod{( p \cdot q)}$ has four congruent solutions?

Studying cryptography, I've seen that given $p$ and $q$ are primes, the equation above should have 4 incongruent solutions.

I see immediately, that $\pm 1$ are solutions, but I don't know how to prove existence of other two.

Also, are there circumstances for which $a^2 \equiv x \mod{( p \cdot q)}$ has four incongruent solutions, e.g. does it always hold for $\gcd({x, p\cdot q}) = 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Here $p, q$ are two distinct odd primes.

If $p = 3$, $q = 5$, for instance, you get the four solutions $a = 1, -1, 4, -4$.

In general the four solutions modulo $pq$ will be the solutions of the four systems
\begin{cases}
a \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p}\\
a \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{q}\\
\end{cases}

With the same approach, $a^{2} \equiv x \pmod{p q}$ has four incongruent solutions if and only if $x$ is a non-zero square modulo $p q$.

Comment: Aha, so I use the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen, yes indeed.

Comment: Also, how many solutions will be there for $x$ relatively prime to $p \cdot q$? - I've verified that there might not be 4 solutions, when $x$ is divisible by either $p$ or $q$.

Comment: 4, or none, according to whether $x$ is a square modulo $pq$ or not. I am assuming $p, q$ to be odd and distinct primes.

Comment: Should you square the $a$ in the four equations?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't necessarily. If $p = 2$ and $q=3$, then

$$0^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 6$$
$$1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 6$$
$$2^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 6$$
$$3^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 6$$
$$4^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 6$$
$$5^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 6$$

and only two are solutions.